How do I get the unique combinations of values that exist in all groupings
I want to know what are the existing combinations of uom values that products have.
Given
df = pd.DataFrame([{'prod_id':3,'uom':'PK'},{'prod_id':3,'uom':'PQT'},{'prod_id':4,'uom':'PK'},{'prod_id':5,'uom':'PQT'},{'prod_id':5,'uom':'PK'},{'prod_id':6,'uom':'SET'},{'prod_id':6,'uom':'ENS'},{'prod_id':7,'uom':'PK'},{'prod_id':7,'uom':'ENS'}])
I want:

[PK, PQT]
[PK]
[SET, ENS]
[PK, ENS]
[PQT, PK]

Ideally the order should not matter, so [PK, PQT] and [PQT, PK] are the equivalent.
I am able to get the combinations of values that each product has easily enough with a groupby and unique.
df.groupby(by='prod_id')['uom'].unique()
but if I try and apply unique() to that result
df.groupby(by='prod_id')['uom'].unique().unique()
I get:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

You can use frozenset
unique_by_id = df.groupby('prod_id').agg({'uom': frozenset}).squeeze().to_list()
unique_as_set = set(unique_by_id)
unique_as_list = [set(i) for i in unique_as_set]
print(unique_as_list)
>>> [{'PQT', 'PK'}, {'SET', 'ENS'}, {'PK', 'ENS'}, {'PK'}]

frozenset is hashable, so it works

The proposed solution works. Thanks.
I am surprised there isn't a more vectorized solution to the problem though.

Other solution: sort the values by uom first, then .groupby()/.agg() and finally .drop_duplicates():
out = df.sort_values(by="uom").groupby("prod_id").agg(list).drop_duplicates()
print(out["uom"].to_list())

Prints:
[['PK', 'PQT'], ['PK'], ['ENS', 'SET'], ['ENS', 'PK']]


EDIT: You can use .drop_duplicates() with subset= to not have duplicates in your output:
out = (
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=["prod_id", "uom"])
    .sort_values(by="uom")
    .groupby("prod_id")
    .agg(list)
    .drop_duplicates()
)
print(out["uom"].to_list())

Prints:
[['PK', 'PQT'], ['PK'], ['ENS', 'SET'], ['ENS', 'PK']]


so the sort does not change what is in the groups, but it will ensure that the lists are always in the same order, so I always get [PK, PQT].
I like this approach

one disadvantage of this approach is that it does not take the unique values from the grouping. So if there are two records with the same uom for a product, it will give a list with two elements instead of one. Similarly, if there are more than 2 records for a product and two have the same uom, the result will have 3 elements and be distinct from a product with the same two unique uom

@Ramsay You can use .drop_duplicates() first to drop any duplicates. I've updated my answer.
